# TV series/movie with a guy that can create electricity between his hands

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

Like the title says I'm trying to find a series or movie that involved a team of people from which I can only remember this one guy always doing some hand motions and getting electricity to spark between his hands. I also remember that he had 1 ring on each hand that helped him conduct the electricity between his hands I think.

Comment: This is quite broad, can you remember anything else at all about it that you could [edit] in? For example, when did you watch this?

Comment: Living actors or cartoon?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you perhaps thinking of *[Mutant X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutant_X_(TV_series))*, an American TV series from 2001 that borrowed heavily from the concept of *The X-Men*?

The story centred around a team of characters with mutant super-powers, one of whom - [Brennan Mulwray](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ajdz2sVmZNI) - was defined as an "elemental electrical", with the ability to generate electricity. He did wear rings on both hands, and he would often manipulate the electricity as if tossing a ball between his hands.

[image]

Comment: That would be my guess too. It was a very distinctive movement.